# to print JSON data in UITableView in dynamic way

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I have some JSON data given below and I want to display it in a table view. I have already succeded using static data, but now I want to do it using dynamic data. How can I do this?

Comment: Learn Json first then only you can fetch data.

Comment: Also, dumping 64kB of raw JSON data into your question will exhaust the RAM of Commodore-64 users viewing this post.

Comment: @RoxFury So I edited your question, removing the unnecessarily present JSON data (which added no value nor context to the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {

return [[[[jsonObject valueForKey:@"companies"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Departments"]count];
 }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
return [[[[[[jsonObject valueForKey:@"companies"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Departments"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Employees"] count];
}



 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

label1.text = [[[[[[[jsonObject valueForKey:@"companies"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Departments"]objectAtIndex:section]valueForKey:@"Employees"]objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"name"];

  }
  - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
     return [[[[[jsonObject valueForKey:@"companies"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Departments"]objectAtIndex:section]valueForKey:@"name"];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, Parse JSON data using JSON Parser and store data in `NSMutableArray` and pass that array to your table view.
Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a JSON parser which will build a data structure (usually nested NSArray, NSDictonary, NSNumber and NSString instances) which you can manipulate as normally. [See my solution for this.](https://github.com/H2CO3/CarbonateJSON)

Side note: if you're not familiar with such a basic concept as creating structured data out of unstructured, you should yet learn a familiarize yourself with stuff like this instead of already making **The Most Bestest iPhone App Yet (TM).**

Comment: dude... i have complete the task successfully... and displayed the json data... also parsed it.. i did this using static data.. but i wanna do it using dynamic data...

Comment: @RoxFury What? I don't understand this. If you have done all this, what else do you want? Perhaps JSON that changes on-the-fly while you're parsing it, or what?

Comment: whatever the data i used in those methods are static.... and i wanna make'em dynamic.... thatz my problem

Comment: @RoxFury But dynamic in what sense? Perhaps make a web API out of it, or dunno what...

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[jsonObject valueForKey:@"companies"] count];
}  this is dynamic in my sense

Comment: and this is static "- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    
    
    return 7;
}"

Comment: that is where the problem lies.... i am stepping wrong at that dynamic way.. n i am here at d home of genius  asking for help

Comment: @RoxFury What's the problem? The collection data type (NSArray or NSDictionary) returns a wrong item count?

Comment: yes.. u got it.. while returning the nsdic object at every step i am going wrong.. at numberOfSectionsInTableView.. at numberOfRowsInSection.. cellForRowAtIndexPath.. titleForHeaderInSection

Comment: @RoxFury What do you expect? What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your JSON data downloaded and parsed, you effectively have static data. You could download and parse your JSON data before you display you table view, then use arrays or dictionaries to specify how you'd like the table view to be layed out. You will need to come of your own way to represent the JSON data as value objects which you can then count and read to supply the table view with the data needed. If ou are going to fetch you data after you have displayed the table view, then once you have the data simply call `-[<tableViewName> reloadData]`

Answer (score 0):

you can create header with back ground color and text alignment.

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

  UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
if (section == 0){
   [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    UILabel * headerLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -5, headerView.frame.size.width, headerView.frame.size.height)];

    headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    headerLabel.text =@"Current Schedule";
    [headerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-ItalicMT" size:18]];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];
    [headerLabel release];

    return headerView;
}
```

}

Comment: i want it in dynamic way.. anyway i found d answer myself.. thanks for responding...